# Configure Cognito User pool to send email from SES in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I have configured SES in master AWS account and Cognito User Pool in other AWS account.
I want to send Email Notification from Cognito using SES of Master account.
I created Identity Policy and attached to SES email address.
However in Cognito User Pool of other AWS account, it does not show any email address. How can I solve this?

I checked Cognito in same account, it shows the Email identity which I have verified in SES but not in Cognito User Pool in other account.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html#user-pool-email-developer this is not possible:

> **Note**: The resources that you create in these steps can't be shared
>   across AWS accounts. For example, you can't configure a user pool in
>   one account with an Amazon SES email address that is in a different
>   account. Therefore, if you use Amazon Cognito in multiple accounts,
>   remember to repeat these steps in each of them.